# Convert 10111 (numbers) into true,false,true,true,true

Tags: jquery

We have dropdown values as 010100 which is dynamic.

Can you help me in converting the values into true,false ?

Value of Offer is 10100 and value of Reject is 10111. So these needs to be converted into

10100 = true,false,true,false,false (with comma)
10111 = true,false,true,true,true (with comma)

So we can use them here as /mygrid.setColumnsVisibility("true,true, true,false,false,false,false");

HTML

```
 <select name="column-display" class="column-display">
 <option name="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
 <option name="offer" value="10111">Offer</option>
 <option name="reject" value="11010">Reject</option>
 </select>
```

JQUERY

```
 $('.column-display').change(function(){
 var dd_val = $(this).val();
   //mygrid.setColumnsVisibility("true,true, true,false,false,false,false");
  });
```

We are using 1.6

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/AWDy4/1/)

Comment: So... any luck with [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a string, you can split it up and then map the individual digits:

```
var x = $.map('10100'.split(''), function(value) {
    return value == '1' ? 'true' : 'false';
}).join(',');
```

See also: [jQuery.map()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

Comment: His question implies/shows an array of Booleans, not strings (so, you only need the assessment itself).

Comment: The function call looks like (for some reason) it's passing a string of comma separated `true`/`false` values. Looks ok to me.

Comment: @DavidThomas It seems to work with option values "10111" and "11010", so it should be a string.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Your solution works well. But the values are not getting replaced in mygrid.setColumnsVisibility; otherwise the columns should hide. Maybe it is the DHTMLX issue.

I have updated the code. http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/AWDy4/19/

Comment: I think I know what the issue is. x should be enclosed by"" and
//mygrid.setColumnsVisibility(x);

Answer (score 1):

replace is what you want.

```
var value = dd_val
            .replace(/1/g, 'true,')
            .replace(/0/g, 'false,');
value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1)
```